# Minimize app instead of exit on back button

Tags: android, react-native

Is there a way to minimize the app when pressing the hardware back button?
I'm currently using [BackAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backandroid.html), but it exits the app.

Edit:

I have logic involved in JS, overriding the lifecycle method in ReactActivity is not sending the event back to JS. Thus, it doesn't work.

```
handleBackButton() {
  const { navigator } = this.refs;
  if (navigator) {
    if (navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1) {
      navigator.pop();
      return true;
    } else if (this.props.selectedTab !== HOME) {
      this.props.selectTab(HOME);
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39639286/3346628

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd have to override the default method but I'm not sure what the actual code to minimize would be. Perhaps mess around with onResume as well?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Your code to minimize
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void minimizeApplication() {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Comment: This is not react native, overriding the lifecycle method in the ReactActivity is messing up with the back button logic placed in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You should try edit changes to the file .

react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/core/DeviceEventManagerModule.java

line 74 ,

```

```
   @ReactMethod
   public void invokeDefaultBackPressHandler() {

//getReactApplicationContext().runOnUiQueueThread(mInvokeDefaultBackPressRunnabl//e);

  this.moveTaskToBack(true); <-- add this line

}
```

```

It should work .